# Which one determined the magnetic field lines, the electron flows or the electromagnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

We understand electrons move in the opposite direction of the electric field because of its negative charge. It was said magnetic fields are generated by current flows. What exactly are current flows? Is it the electrons or the electric fields?